# Having problems with my Pig latin translator

Tags: python

I just started to learn programming and one of my tasks was to create a pig Latin translator in python

Heres my code:

```
def pyglatin():
    words = input("Enter a word please:").split()
    for word in words:
    print(word[1:] + word[0] +"ay", end = " ")      

if word[0] == "a" or "i" or "u" or "e" or "o":
    print(word[0] + word[1:] + "way", end = " ")
    

pyglatin()
```

My problem is that the result keeps printing both words:

```
Enter a word please:hello
ellohay helloway
```

Also, how can I make the users input all lowercase?

Thanks :)

Comment: (1) `if word[0] in 'aeiou': print(...) else print(...)`; (2) `words = input(...).lower().split()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here. Your indentation is off, but most importantly, your `if` statement will always return `True`. To make a comparison against many values, replace `word[0] == "a" or "i" or "u" or "e" or "o"` with `word[0] in {"a", "i", "u", "e", "o"}`, otherwise the 2nd part of your statement will always evaluate to `True`.

Perhaps this is what you're after:

```
def pyglatin():
    words = input("Enter a word please:").split()
    for word in words:
      print(word[1:] + word[0] +"ay", end = " ")      

    if word[0] in {"a", "i", "u", "e", "o"}:
        print(word[0] + word[1:] + "way", end = " ")
    
pyglatin()
```

Output:

```
Enter a word please:hello
ellohay
```

```
Enter a word please:abc
bcaay abcway
```

To make the input lowercase, use `words = input("Enter a word please:").lower().split()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = input("Enter a word please:")
words=words.split()
for word in words:
   print(word[1:] + word[0] +"ay", end = " ")      
   if word[0] == "a" or word[0]=="i" or word[0]=="u" or word[0]=="e" or 
word[0]=="o":
      print(word[0] + word[1:] + "way", end = " ")
```